# How redirect apache2 to jboss web service and consume with php

Tags: php, apache, web-services, jboss, wsdl

I'm trying to redirect a web service from apache2 to jboss, and later consume this with php.

I succes can redirect request, and see the wsdl in the browser, but when I call with php:

```
$server = new SoapServer('http://subdomain.midomain.com/FirmaElectronica/WebService?wsdl');

var_dump($server);
// Returns:
// object(SoapServer)[1]
// public 'service' => resource(1, Unknown)

var_dump($server->__getFunctions());
// Error, Call to undefined method

$salida = $server->hello('mat');
// Error, Call to undefined method
```

My apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.midomain.com
ServerAlias midomain.com
# ProxyRequests On
# ProxyVia On
ProxyPass "/FirmaElectronica" "http://10.128.0.2:8080/FirmaElectronica"
ProxyPassReverse "/FirmaElectronica" "http://10.128.0.2:8080/FirmaElectronica"
</VirtualHost>
```

Also tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.midomain.com
ServerAlias midomain.com
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
ProxyPass "/FirmaElectronica" "http://10.128.0.2:8080/FirmaElectronica"
ProxyPassReverse "/FirmaElectronica" "http://10.128.0.2:8080/FirmaElectronica"
</VirtualHost>
```

And a few more different configuration for apache, in every case I can see wsdl in browser, but when a do a php call, everything brokes.

Any idea?

Comment: To consume services you must use a SoapClient http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved, the problem was use SoapCliente and a bad configuration in web service url in windfly with jboss